# Arreglo de punteros a structs en c++

Tags: array, c

1. Tengo que generar un arreglo de 3 punteros.

```
arreglo = [puntero1, puntero2, puntero3];
```

2. Puntero1 apunta a una estructura de datos de tipo Book.

```
struct Book{
int pages;
};
arreglo[0] = new Book
```

3. puntero 2 apunta a un arreglo de punteros a structs Book

```
arreglo[1] = [pointer4, pointer5]
pointer4 = new Book
pointer5 = newBook
```

6 Pointer3 apunta a un arreglo de tres punteros que replica el principal. Es decir; en su primer posicion el puntero apunta a un Book. En su segunda posicion hay un arreglo de structs Book. En su tercera posicion hay un arreglo de tres punteros que apuntan a una struct Book cada uno.

```
arreglo[2] = [pointer4, pointer5, pointer6]
pointer4 = new Book
pointer5 = [Book, Book]
pointer6 = [pointer7, pointer8, pointer9]
pointer7 = new Book
pointer8 = new Book
pointer9 = new Book
```

Tengo problemas para representar los punteros que necesito definir en el arreglo principal.
He intentado lo siguiente:

```
//multiLevelArrayOfPointesToStructs.h
#ifndef MULTILEVELARRAYPOINTERS_H_INCLUDED
#define MULTILEVELARRAYPOINTERS_H_INCLUDED

struct Book{
    int pages;
    float price;
};

void inicio(){
     Book ***myBook;
     myBook = new Book**[3];
     myBook[0]=  new Book;
     myBook[1] = new Book*[2];
     myBook[2] = new Book*[3];
     //myBook first position
     myBook[0] -> pages = 500;
     myBook[0]->price = 30;


#endif // MULTILEVELARRAYPOINTERS_H_INCLUDED
```

Naturalmente, recibo un error,marcado en la linea que define myBook[0] = newBook, el cual dice que "cannot convert Book* to Book**"

Sin embargo si trato de corregir asi:

```
myBook[0] = newBook*;
```

Ya no puedo acceder a las propiedades de la strcut Book

```
myBook[0] -> pages = 500;
myBook[0]->price = 30;
```

Comment: ¿C++ o C? La etiqueta contradice al título.

Answer (score 0):

No es posible tener un arreglo de tipos diferentes de forma directa.

Para ese propósito puedes usar un `tuple`:

```
auto tuple = make_tuple(1, 0.1, 'a');
```

Pero en este caso lo más conveniente es usar un struct como este:

```
struct Test {
    int *e1;
    int (*e2)[2];
    Test* e3;
};
```

El cual puedes usar así:

```
void print(const Test *test){
    if (!test)
        return;

    cout << *test->e1 << '\n';
    cout << (*test->e2)[0] << ", " << (*test->e2)[1] << '\n';
    print(test->e3);
}

int main(){
    int a = 1;
    int b[2] = { 3, 4 };
    Test t { &a, &b, nullptr };
    
    print(&t);
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##XVDLboMwELz7K6apRAARqYTeoPmK3loOjnEjS2AsP3qJ8u10DaSk3YOlmdnZ3bEw5nARYpqelRZ96CQaNTpvJR9OjAWn9AWaD9IZLiSc72rGSA7C4106jysDldIeuSzrX5Dm8ph9HNuFiZ05ZFWzG9m/R9XBWGpLxajdOij39GbruC@kTzOeYSwrfbCa3BGIMXg0zeI5nGQZwf5T7@s/cnrX6ZSXNjK7Arv/Stlu7tm@nLY2VBkdzVjMNHCl02wLzPGGh8hnikvMFVWBV9y25KBfQsILJOcCOvS98faux3pYmvi4bpp@AA). Ten en cuenta que deberías cambiar `int` por `Book` y al struct le puedes cambiar el nombre por el que más te guste.

---

Si lo prefieres, puedes usar `void*`. De esta forma generas un arreglo de punteros a cualquier tipo. Solo que es bastante incómodo obtener el valor que buscas:

```
void print(const void *test){
    auto arreglo = (const char**)test;
    auto puntero = (int*)arreglo[0];
    auto punteroArreglo = (int(*)[2])arreglo[1];
    cout << *puntero << '\n';
    cout << (*punteroArreglo)[0] << ", " << (*punteroArreglo)[1] << '\n';
    if (arreglo[2])
        print(arreglo[2]);
}

int main(){
    int a = 1;
    int b[2] = { 3, 4 };
    void *t[3] { &a, &b, nullptr };
        
    print(t);
}
```